# void* pointer casting while scheduling a thread

Tags: c++, casting, pthreads, void-pointers

I have a function called by a thread.this function has a unique argument which is queue::my_queue . So I need to perform a cast on void pointer in the method called by the thread as follows:

```
void *AddPacket(void *Ptr) 
{     queue<int> my_queue = (queue*)Ptr ; 
       my_queue.push(byte) ; 
}
```

and in the main, I do:

```
int main()
{   // do business
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &AddPacket, (void*)queue) ; 
}
```

But both conversions are wrong.

the first conversion leads to the error:

request for member ‘push' in ‘my_queue’, which is of non-class type ‘queue*’

and the second one:

invalid cast from type ‘queue’ to type ‘void*’

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
queue<int> *my_queue = (queue<int> *)Ptr ;
my_queue->push(byte) ;

pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &AddPacket, (void*)&queue) ;
```

.. something along those lines, anyway

Answer (score 4):

You try to cast object type to pointer type. It is not allowed. I guess you are new to C++, so  I post corrected code here to unpuzzle you and get you going, but please read a book on C++:

```
queue<int>* my_queue = (queue<int>*)Ptr ; 
my_queue->push(byte) ;

pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &AddPacket, &queue) ;
```

Remember to read about pointers on C++ :)

Comment: ..needs the dot changing to -> as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change both the thread function and the thread creation:

```
// thread entry point:
void *AddPacket(void *Ptr)
{
    reinterpret_cast<std::queue<int>*>(Ptr)->push(byte);
}
```

```
// thread creation:

std::queue<int> q;
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &AddPacket, &q);
//                                        ^^^^ **pointer** to "q";
//                                        conversion to void* is implied
```